# Seconds and Microseconds (Unix time) to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#

I have two uint32 variables. They represent a Unix timestamp in seconds and microseconds. The first variable holds the seconds and the second holds the microseconds. How can I add them together and convert them to a DateTimeOffset. I'd like an answer specific to .Net 4.6 which has the new FromUnixTimeSeconds() method and an answer that will work with code prior to .Net 4.6.

Comment: So, just call FromUnixTimeSeconds with seconds, then add microseconds to result?

Comment: There's no AddMicroseconds method on DateTimeOffset. I guess I need ticks first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsecond is 1 / 1.000.000 of a second. `DateTimeOffset` indeed does not have `AddMicroseconds`, but it has `AddTicks`. Tick is 1 / 10.000.000 of a second, so:

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(seconds).AddTicks(microSeconds * 10);
```

Prior to .NET 4.6 you can do something like this:

```
new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddSeconds(seconds).AddTicks(microSeconds * 10);
```

Comment: [Microseconds and Nanoseconds are available in .NET 7](https://davecallan.com/microseconds-and-nanoseconds-available-in-net-7/)